# How to call an handler from an URL in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm writting a Yesod application and I need to be to call a handler internally from a URL or a Route.

What I mean is when you send a request to Yesod, at some point is parses the URL to a `Route` and then call to the correct handler using a dispatch function. I would like to be able to call those functions manually so that I can create a route from a URL and the call the appropriate handler.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can just call the handler function you wrote, same as you would call any other function. I'm assuming there's something I'm missing or misunderstanding?

Comment: The problem is actuall to find the correct handler to call. For example, given "/a/1" I would like to find the handler corresponding to route "/a" apply "1" to it and pass me the result. I can convert the string to a route and pattern match on the route to find the correct handler, but that's already what Yesod does each time it processes a request, so I instead of reinventing the wheel, I would like to be able to use Yesod machinery.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `parseRoute` method of [ParseRoute](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.6.16.1/docs/Yesod-Core.html#t:ParseRoute) typeclass work for you?

Comment: parseRoute does half of the job (a third in fact). The first job is to split the url into components, the second is to convert those components into a route (which is what parseRoute does) and the third is to find and call the handler corresponding to the route.